# Changing working copy repository URL from svn to http protocol

Tags: svn, protocols

I have a checked out repository on something like

```
svn://sub.domain.com/path/to/repo/trunk
```

and i need to switch to something like

```
http://domain.com/path/to/repo/trunk
```

i've tried the "switch --relocate" command but this is what i get

```
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'http://domain.com/path/to/repo/trunk'; please relocate
```

Comment: this is useful, as PhpStorm 8 could not seem to do this from inside the client, and I couldn't remember the command to relocate the repo manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you have written the right urls and 
then try this from the root of the working copy try this:

```
svn switch --relocate svn:///HOST_1/PATH_1 http://HOST_2/PATH_2
```

Answer (score 2):

I must to note: `--relocate` option is deprecated for `svn switch`, and, as written in error-message, you have to use relocate command

If you must change `svn://sub.domain.com` to `http://domain.com`, you can use 1-st form of relocate command

From `svn help relocate`

> relocate FROM-PREFIX TO-PREFIX [PATH...]
>
> ...
>
> FROM-PREFIX and TO-PREFIX are initial substrings of the working copy's current and new URLs, respectively.

In your case (in working copy root)

`svn relocate svn://sub.domain.com http://domain.com`

and check `svn info` result after relocate